# ASP + restrict use of css file to child page

Tags: .net, css

I have a master page and some child page.

I have defined few class for css. Now i want that some of the child pages can use that css but not every child page. Master page should use that css file. How to restrict the use of css file??

Comment: Can you give an example of your code

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** It depends what you mean.... You said you made class's so therefore you don't need to include them in the child pages.

**CSS**

```
.Main{ background-color:blue; }
```

**Normal Page**

```
<body class="Main">
      ....
</body>
```

**Other Pages that you don't want the CSS Class**

```
<body>
    .....
</body>
```

or if you added CSS to one of the selectors then you will need to overwrite them in your child pages for example

**CSS**

```
body{ background-color:blue; }
```

**Child Page where you don't want the style**

```
 <style type="text/css">
      body {background-color:green;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    ...... 
 </body>
```